# How to implement auto conversion from one type to another?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

On my class I have implemented implicit operators and also IConvertible interface. When using class with NHibernate (this is not issue with it), I get the Object of type "mytype" cannot be converted to "string". When I look at the stack trace is shows that error occurs in System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType method. If I decompile the code it further invokes Binder.ChangeType, so it looks like it does not use IConvertible interface. Binder is abstract class that lives in System.Reflection namespace. How do I provide a knowledge to the system to be able to auto-convert from my type into string. I want to project a value (component) object, that has several int properties into a string, and I don't want to do extra steps.

We have a component PolicyNumber mapped as

```
 Component(x => x.PolicyNumber, m =>
            {
                m.Map(x => x.Year, "Year");
                m.Map(x => x.ClientNumber, "ClientNumber");
                m.Map(x => x.OptionNumber, "BidOptionNumber");
            }).ReadOnly();
```

In QueryOver I want to project this into a string in the format year-clientNumber-bidOptionNumber. This is just one example, we have more of value objects that we use instead of magic strings.

```
 .Select(Projections.Group<ClientPolicy>(x => clientPolicy.PolicyNumber))
                            .WithAlias(() => dto.ClientPolicyNumber)
```

If one defines PolicyNumber on dto to be of a type string, than I would like ToString() to happen. I worked around this issue by providing a Value property on the object, but it would be nice if this auto conversion would happen. It seems like it is not possible, based on the call stack trace. Also I do not want to create IUserType implementation for each value object, as there are many.

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you're trying to do? My first reaction - because this is NHibernate related - was to look at the `IUserType` interface so you can define a custom mapping between a column to your custom type and back again.

Comment: @Anthony: Added mapping and more info about what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  There is no way to create an implicit conversion *at runtime* (which is quite different from an implicit conversion at compile time) between your type and any arbitrary type.  You'll need to have your code do the conversion explicitly.

Comment: I thought that one could provide a custom binder somehow for the type.

Comment: @epitka You can build a framework for doing so yourself, and you can use it to convert types, but there is no way for you to build an implicit conversion into C# such that any existing C# operations dependent on an implicit conversion will work.